# How to transpose this data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have data in google sheet I just want to fetch that data in my other sheet but in transpose 
Here is ex:

```
Column A    | Column B    | Column C
=================================
site1.com   | Name 1      | Name 2
site2.com   | Name 3      | Name 4 
site3.com   | Name 5      | Name 6
```

Want to data like this

```
Column A    | Column B    | Column C
=================================
site1.com   | site2.com   | site3.com
Name 1      | Name 3      | Name 5 
Name 2      | Name 4      | Name 6
```

I don't want to enter formula manually in every row so is arryformula can do this automatic.

I'm trying this but not able to what I want.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!$B2:B300 & Sheet1!$L2:L300))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you can do just:

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:C3)
```

or:

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("A1:C"&COUNTA(A:A)))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2:L"&COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A)+1)), "offset 1")
```

Comment: here sheet link data in sheet1 and need in sheet 2 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zAWnfRGBSntjSLSvkMskRntNkdMjojclfCz8AAbeRXI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j8iFs94rDlNnFuooZCP2QIWplFj6GPvekY8zu1IDs_g/edit#gid=1301974344

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({TRANSPOSE(SORT(FILTER(A:A, A:A<>""))); 
 SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(ISNUMBER(QUERY(QUERY({A:B; A:A, C:C}, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "offset 1", 0)), SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(QUERY({A:B; A:A, C:C}, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col2"), 
 "limit 0"), " ", "♦"), )),,999^99)), " ")), "♦" , " ")})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks, some help need in this, I do this to transpose A:A in 2nd sheet =transpose(filter(Sheet1!A2:A, len(Sheet1!A2:A)))     L column is last column of my data and its total 378 rows  please help me in this

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: here sheet link data in sheet1 and need in sheet 2 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zAWnfRGBSntjSLSvkMskRntNkdMjojclfCz8AAbeRXI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j8iFs94rDlNnFuooZCP2QIWplFj6GPvekY8zu1IDs_g/edit#gid=737178459

Comment: you mean the difference in A1 and A3 in Sheet4? you want to force the order of 1st row?

Comment: Please lookinto sheet 4 now I want data like now . hope you got my point Column a and Column B i update

Comment: paste in Sheet4!A3: `=TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A2:L"&COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A)+1))`

Comment: (Y)  Thank you so much , you are best .. have a nice day